# Selecting element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following HTML in one of my apps,

```
<article class="item">
       <header>
           <h1>Heading</h1>
           <div class="tasks meta">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-tab item-tab" data-tab="items">Sub Items</a>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-tab item-tab" data-tab="files">Files</a>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-tab item-tab" data-tab="description">Notes</a>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-tab item-tab" data-tab="tasks">Tasks</a>
           </div>
       </header>
       <div class="item-content">
           <div class="tab-content description"></div>
           <div class="tab-content files"></div>
           <div class="tab-content tasks"></div>
           <div class="tab-content description"></div>
      </div>

      <article class="item">
       <header>
           <h1>Heading</h1>
           <div class="tasks meta">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-tab item-tab" data-tab="items">Sub Items</a>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-tab item-tab" data-tab="files">Files</a>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-tab item-tab" data-tab="description">Notes</a>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-tab item-tab" data-tab="tasks">Tasks</a>
           </div>
       </header>
       <div class="item-content">
           <div class="tab-content description"></div>
           <div class="tab-content files"></div>
           <div class="tab-content tasks"></div>
           <div class="tab-content description"></div>
      </div>
   </article>

   <article class="item">
       <header>
           <h1>Heading</h1>
           <div class="tasks meta">
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-tab item-tab" data-tab="items">Sub Items</a>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-tab item-tab" data-tab="files">Files</a>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-tab item-tab" data-tab="description">Notes</a>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-tab item-tab" data-tab="tasks">Tasks</a>
           </div>
       </header>
       <div class="item-content">
           <div class="tab-content description"></div>
           <div class="tab-content files"></div>
           <div class="tab-content tasks"></div>
           <div class="tab-content description"></div>
      </div>
   </article>

</article>
```

What I am trying to a click a `.btn-tab` element, and from there add an `.active` class to the closest `.tab-content` that also has the same class as the `.btn-tab` data-item attribute.

All I seem to be able to do however is add an active class to all the tab-content element that also have the matching class and data-item.

** Example **

If I click on the first Sub Items link then all the `.tab-content .items` elements get the active class however I just want the one closest to click to get the class.

Here is my javascript,

```
var clicked = $(e.currentTarget),
        clickedTab = clicked.data("tab");

    var clickedParent = clicked.parents('.item');

    clickedParent.css("border", "1px solid red");

    clickedParent.find(".item-tabs").find(".tab-content." + clickedTab).addClass("active");
```

Comment: use closest() method...

Comment: tried that but it cannot find the element.

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with your HTML/CSS/jQuery? That would be easier to work with.

Comment: looks like the first `article` is not closed properly, it is closed after the last `article`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VMz8y/4/ ?

Answer (score 0):

This is it: Se this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rgx9/)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.btn-tab', function () {
        console.log($(this).closest('article.item'))
        $(this)
            .closest('article.item')
                .find('.tab-content')
                    .removeClass('active')
                    .filter('.' + $(this).data('tab'))
                        .addClass('active')
    })
})
```

BTW: you have an nesting error in you HTML: The first `<article>` is wrapped around the rest. I think it should close before the next one.